# How to check that my recovery disk is working correctly?

Tags: macos, usb, recovery, data-recovery, internet-recovery

My iMac has recently stopped working after trying to upgrade the OS (I believe it came from El Capitan). Now, when I boot it I only see the folder with a question mark.

When I boot it in "reinstall OS mode", it doesn't work:

- <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> tells me that "a necessary component is missing" and cannot download a proper version of the OS
- <kbd>Maj ⇧</kbd> + <kbd>Opt ⌥</kbd> + <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> tries to download OS X Lion, but then fails installing it because "You cannot upgrade this version of macOS because a new version is installed"
- <kbd>Opt ⌥</kbd> + <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> tries to download an OS, but then stays stuck on the apple on the screenshot.

I have been able to download a MacOsInstall.dmg file directly from Apple, and mount it on a USB drive (on my Windows computer, using transmac), however, when I plug in this file and boot using <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>, the USB drive does not appear in the list of the drives they propose me to boot from. Is there any possibility for me to check that the USB stick that I created is correctly configured?

My objective here is to find a way to make the computer work again. If impossible, I'd settle for a recovery of my data for which I had no backup.

Comment: What year iMac do you have?  If it’s after 2011, it supports Internet Recovery.

Comment: @Allan Probably a Late 2011 iMac if Shift+Opt+Cmd+R tries to install Lion.

Comment: Plug in a  USB drive with enough space and see if you can install to that. If you can, boot off of that drive and then do your data recovery. Once that’s done you should be able to wipe the internal drive and do a clean install